# C# DataTypes Confusion From Documentation

Tags: c#, .net

I was going through the documentation for "Floating-point numeric types (C# reference)" at MSDN, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types.

It has a table, "Characteristics of the floating-point types,"  describing the approximate ranges for the different floating datatypes that C# deals with. What I do not understand is why both the MIN and MAX in "Approximate range" column are both positive and negative. Skipping a link click, here is the table,

| C# type/keyword | Approximate range | Precision | Size | .NET type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| float | ±1.5 x 10<sup>−45</sup> to ±3.4 x 10<sup>38</sup> | ~6-9 digits | 4 bytes | System.Single |
| double | ±5.0 × 10<sup>−324</sup> to ±1.7 × 10<sup>308</sup> | ~15-17 digits | 8 bytes | System.Double |
| decimal | ±1.0 x 10<sup>-28</sup> to ±7.9228 x 10<sup>28</sup> | 28-29 digits | 16 bytes | System.Decimal |

Why does the approximate range on both the MIN and MAX have a ±? Should it not be a `-` for the MIN, and `+` for the MAX, as it does for the Integer type here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types? Maybe I misunderstood something about floating points.

Thank you.

Comment: It's just a simple way of indicating that the MIN and the MAX are the same number, just one negative, the other positive.

Comment: I think he is not paying attention to the minus sign of the exponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing here is the sign of the exponent.

> The double and float types are used for approximations and should be avoided for exact values.
> Some programmers make the mistake of using them because there is a performance gain in the execution of complex calculations in relation to the decimal type.

### Explaining what I think is confusing you

> I'll lower the exponent to make it easier to understand

> ± is a replecement for "more or less", since float and double types are recommended for approximations.

The first part is for values that are less than one (fractions).

- **±1.5 x 10^−5** = "more or less" 0,000015

The seconde part is for integers.

- **±3.4 x 10^5** = "more or less" 340.000

Comment: Yep, seems like I made a mistake of taking float points for exact values. Now this makes more sense to think about really.

Comment: I think I make a mistake here too. The "±" is a replace for "more or less". I will fix the answer and let's pretend that never happen ^^'.

Comment: Hahahahaa, sure. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it could be made clearer, but this expresses the smallest absolute value that can be expressed as well as the largest absolute value that can be expressed by the given data type.  To take an example, if we consider `double`, it is impossible to represent 3e-324 - it would become approximately 5.0e-324, which is `double.Epsilon` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.epsilon?view=net-7.0).

These values work for both positive and negative values, hence the use of ±.

Comment: This makes somewhat sense. What made me confused was the MIN value, let's say, has both a plus and a minus sign. I was picturing a real number line where this value exists at equidistant from the center, but then the value for the MAX also has a range on the number line.

For `System.Double`, with `±5.0 × 10−324`, I have two values, `-5.0 × 10−324` and`+5.0 × 10−324`, and with `±1.7 × 10308` I have `-1.7 × 10308` and `+1.7 × 10308`, so in total 4 values on a number line. I was initially confused about the approximation here, but it makes somewhat sense now.